# R - ddply and incrementing a counter

Tags: r, scope, plyr

I am using `ddply` to split up a data frame and send the chunks to a function. Before the `ddply` line, I set `i=1`. Then inside the function I am incrementing `i` so that each chunk of data gets a new number. When I run this, however, `i` is being reset to 1 each time the function is called. I assume this is because the `i` outside the function is being reassigned each time `ddply` sends a new chunk of data. Is there a way to increment outside the function and send that number along with the data?

EDIT::
Here is the calling line:

```
rseDF <- ddply(rseDF, .(TestCompound), .fun = setTheSet)
```

Here is the function:

```
##Set The Set Column
setTheSet <- function(df) {
if (df[,"TestCompound"] == "DNS000000001") df[,"Set"] <- "Control"
else {df[,"Set"] <- i
i <<- i+1}
return(df)
}
```

Comment: This sounds a somewhat odd thing to do with `ddply`.  Perhaps if you expand a little bit on your use case and provide a minimal example, we can advise on alternative design patterns.  (It sounds like you are really busy with a loop, in which case `ldply` might be more appropriate?)

Comment: Thanks Andrie. I am actually not using a loop. The whole reason for using `ddply` was to eliminate a for loop. The function simply creates a column and puts `i` into it for all members. As far as I can tell, this is the "Split-Apply-Combine" strategy that ddply() was made for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is just a normal scoping issue where you, if you insist on doing this, need to use `<<-` for the global assignment:

```
R> library(plyr)                    ## load plyr
R> i <- 1                           ## set counter
R> DF <- data.frame(a=rep(letters[1:3], each=3), b=1:9)
R> DF                               ## boring but simple data frame
  a b
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
4 b 4
5 b 5
6 b 6
7 c 7
8 c 8
9 c 9
R> ddply(DF, .(a), function(x) mean(x$b))     ## summarized
  a V1
1 a  2
2 b  5
3 c  8
R> ddply(DF, .(a), function(x) { i <<- i + 1; data.frame(i=i, res=mean(x$b)) })
  a i res
1 a 2   2
2 b 3   5
3 c 4   8
R>
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I figured R would have a simple solution for this, but Google seems to be almost useless when looking for specific answers.

Comment: Pleasure -- and as an aside, Google is very useful if you do things like quering via the http://rseek.org site, or simply add terms like 'r-help' or restrict to the gmane.org list archive or ...

Comment: @ dirk also, if you use gmail and are logged in, and click on enough R related links, they will become promoted for your account. I found it very hard to find R related links when i started but now they're almost always at the top

Answer (score 2):

You could use `assign` to change the value of the global variable from within your function:

```
> x <- 10

> test1 <- function() { x <- 3 }
> test1()
> x
[1] 10

> test2 <- function() { assign('x', 3, envir = .GlobalEnv) }
> test2()
> x
[1] 3
```

As you can see, `test1` doesn't do what you expect, whereas `test2` does.

**edit:** A more concise approach that I've just discovered by reading the manual is to use the "superassignment" operator `<<-`:

```
> test3 <- function() { x <<- 17 }
> test3()
> x
[1] 17
```

The manual [explains](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Assignment-within-functions) the semantics of the simple assignment within a function:

> Note that any ordinary assignments done within the function are local
>   and temporary and are lost after exit from the function. Thus the
>   assignment `X <- qr(X)` does not affect the value of the argument in the
>   calling program.